# How to link resources outside the application directory for ASP.NET MVC applications?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a Javascript source file that is common to different projects, which I want to move out of application specific directories and move into a common spot which all my projects can reference.

However I can't seem to reference the file in the `<script>` tag of my Views. I've tried using the `..` symbol to escape up the directory chain but the HTML page doesn't seem to recognize the resource. Which would make sense because how would the HTML page know about a directory above the root of the application? Speaking of the root, I tried using `~` to indicate the application root and then I got the following error:

`Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory`

Is it simply not possible to link to outside resources?

**EDIT:** After adding the `ASP.NET v4.0` app pool to the access control list for the `.js` file, the `GET` request succeeded. However, in my controller action where I am grabbing the file, I am going through the virtual directory I had previously created. If this is the case, shouldn't I just be able to source the file using the virtual directory instead of my controller action? When I try to do this, the `GET` request fails again. When I try to navigate to this source manually, I get an `Internal Server Error 500.19`. It seems to be looking for a nonexistent `web.config` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem, I ended up duping some files anyway but I am happy with the result since I only have to make changes to one file (at the library location) and it gets propagated to the rest of my projects.

I set up a folder in the general `Scripts` folder (which we'll call `lib`). Within `lib` I added the library `.js` files as links, so they are pointing to the library location. This way I can edit the files directly within my project, but the changes are really happening at the library location. To make sure that the files still get included in the project when it is deployed, I added a pre-build batch script which copies the files to the folder with `xcopy`. This way, the changes can be made from the file directly or within my project, but the up to date files are always copied over before a build. This solves the double-dot issue of escaping out of the root directory as well.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it simply not possible to link to outside resources?

Not directly, no.  This has nothing to do with ASP.NET or MVC or anything like that.  It's simply a matter of whether or not the client can access the server-side file.  If that file is outside of the web server's root, it can't be accessed.  (Take a moment to imagine a world where any file on your server could be downloaded by any client who could specify the path to it.  And then realize that things like that [have happened](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimda).)

Any file that's not directly accessible by clients would need to be served by the web application in some way.  This is a common approach for serving image files from a database, for example.  You might have a single entry point page, something like:

```
/Scripts/Script/123
```

Which your markup would reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Script/123"></script>
```

Then in your server-side code for that action you would capture the identifier for the script being referenced (doesn't have to be an integer, I'm just using that as an example, you just want to be able to identify a file in some way), read the file from the disk, and write the file to the client.  Which could be something as simple as:

```
return File("path/to/file.js", "application/javascript");
```

The browser doesn't care if it's a "file" or if it's being fed as a string to the output.  This is because HTTP doesn't have "files".  As long as the response body has the right content and the headers specify the right kind of content, it's no different from downloading the "file" directly.

Comment: I am already returning a `View` object with a passed-in view model from my controller actions, is there a separate way of detecting and passing the `File` with the path?

Comment: @F.Ali: It's not really clear what you're asking there, and I suspect you're mixing up some terminology or some HTTP concepts.  Your overall page returns the View for that "page", but each resource on the page is a separate request to the server.  Resources which can't be served by the server (since they're outside its root) would need to be served through the application, still as their own requests.  You don't need a view model at all for these requests since they're just returning files.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I realized that I could treat that `/Scripts/Script/123` identifier as the name of a controller action and then respond appropriately with the right file, like your example above. The resource still fails to load, and when I navigate to that controller action via URL, I am getting a "Could not find a part of the path" error, and I am absolutely certain that the path does exist. Is it possible that the application is not seeing the path? I tried adding it as a virtual directory in IIS as well which did not work.

Comment: @F.Ali: What throws that error specifically?  The call to `File()`?  What is the exact path you're using?  The notion of "creating a virtual directory" implies that you're treating the path as a URL, when it should be a file system path.

Comment: The filename parameter for `File()` is "Common/jsresource.js" (where Common is a virtual folder). I load the view and inspect it in and I can see the resource GET request failed (the action is not called). I navigate to the action manually, but since it doesn't return a view I get an error page saying "Server error." The call to File() does not cause the error, I believe the error is there because that controller action does not return a usable view, but a resource.

Comment: Controller actions don't have to return views, they return action results.  A file is a perfectly valid action result.  If you're getting a server error that usually means there's an exception being thrown.  How have you actually debugged this?  How have you confirmed that the action isn't invoked?  You said earlier there was an error about not being able to find a path, what throws that error?  Don't assume things, debug them.

Comment: The controller action was not invoked because my path in the `script src` attribute was incorrect. When I fixed it I definitely saw the action being invoked. With that being said, `File()` was not causing an error, because I stepped through the code and there was no exception thrown throughout the action method. Once I stepped out of the controller action (and the app returned the `FilePathResult` to the client) is when I was seeing the error. I did manage another workaround for this issue, but I thank you for all your help, I still learned a lot. Cheers.